# Send http-get request to many hosts at same time with linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, httprequest, wget

Is it possible to send an http-get request to many hosts at same time with linux bash tools?

At the moment I do

```
wget -O- http://192.168.1.20/get_data-php > out.log
```

But I need to request all `192.168.1.0/17` IPs.

Comment: Sure, you can put them all in the background (with `&`) and concatenate the results afterwards with: `wget ... > out1.txt &; wget ... > out2.txt &; ....; wait; cat out*.txt > allout.txt`

Comment: Btw, are you sure about `/17`? That'll be `[192.168.0.1, 192.168.127.254]` (32766 addresses).

Comment: Yes I am sure about the mask. It's all internal network, so no problem. But I was more thinking about some command like wget where I can use netmasks. Or maybe netcat ...

Comment: Not that I know of - and if you find one that does, making it do all the requests at the same time may not be possible. It'll probably do them one at a time.

Comment: Of course not exactly at same time, I think I will end up writing a short script which loops through and does the request for me

Comment: Yes that was what I had in mind in my first comment and what it looks like Drejc has implemented in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
rm address.txt allout.txt # remove old file with addresses and contents
nmap -n -sn 192.168.1.0/17 -oG - | awk '/Up$/{print $2}' > address.txt # get all active hosts and store into a file address.txt

while IFS="" read -r add || [ -n "$add" ]
do
  wget -q -O- http://"$add"/get_data-php > out"$add".log & # for every address create file with wget content
done < address.txt

wait

cat out*.log > allout.txt # put all .log file contents to allout.txt

rm -r out*.log # remove all created .log files
```

Comment: Thanks, I accepted this solution because it checks for active hosts first.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is to use bash *brace expansion*:

```
wget -O- http://192.168.{0..127}.{1..254}/get_data-php >>out.log
```

... if performance is not a concern (because it will run the requests sequentially).

Of course there are ways to run requests in parallel, but I guess that that is out of scope for this question.

Comment: I even did not know the possibility of brace expansion, thanks a lot for this! I still used to write the script to check online hosts first.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Drejc's answer, but avoids messing with temporary files and deals better with a process limit that is lower than the number of hosts (e.g. if you have 1000s of hosts).

```sh
#!/bin/sh

nmap -T5 -n -sn 192.168.1.0/17 -oG - |
  awk '/Up$/{print $2}' |
  parallel -j0 wget -q -O- http://{}/get_data-php > allout.txt
```